# URL changed, remap it with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)signup(.*)$ $1register$2

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|img|js|css|libs|uploads)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Does anyone have an idea why http://localhost/site/signup doesn't work, while http://localhost/site/register does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)signup(.*)$ $1register$2 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|img|js|css|libs|uploads)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```